# Divide an acute triangle into $3$ mirror-symmetric shapes

Tags: geometry

Find three ways to divide any acute triangle into $3$ mirror-symmetric shapes.

Two ways, using the circumcenter and incenter, are easy.

[image: example]

What is the third way?

Comment: I strongly suspect the three resulting portions are not all of the same generic type, e.g., isosceles triangles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take triangle $ABC$, let $AH$ be the altitude. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$, 
$N$ the midpoint of $AC$. Then $ABC$ can be decomposed into isosceles triangle $BMH$, 
isosceles triangle $HNC$, and the quadrilateral $AMHN$ which has symmetric axis $MN$.

Comment: Yep.  Nice.  Confirming my intuitions in my comment.  (+1)

Answer (score 2):

In your second graph for incenter, the 3 curved polygons
$DIGH$, $EGI$ and $FHG$ are also mirror-symmetric and you can use them to decompose your triangle.

[image: A triangle into 3 curved polygon]